# Smoothness between showing more and showing less

Tags: css, reactjs, toggle

I have a div that allows a user to toggle between showing more of the div's contents, and showing less of them.

The div simply contains a list of items.

[image: showing more]

What I want to do is animate the transition between showing more and showing less; the transition between small div and large.

[image: showing less]

At the moment it jumps.

In a real world example, I may never set or know the height of the div. What's a good way to animate the transition?

[Here is a link to a Codepen which will demonstrate what I am going for.](http://codepen.io/alanbuchanan/pen/bpvRbE/)

React

```
var Box = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            showingMore: false
        };
    },
    handleShowToggle: function() {
        this.setState({
            showingMore: !this.state.showingMore
        });
    },
    render: function(){
        var {showingMore} = this.state;
        var showText = showingMore ? 'Show Less' : 'Show More';
        var style = {display: showingMore ? 'block' : 'none'}
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li style={style}>Sometimes show me</li>
                    <li style={style}>Sometimes show me</li>
                    <li style={style}>Sometimes show me</li>
                    <li>Always show me</li>
                    <li style={style}>Sometimes show me</li>
                    <li onClick={this.handleShowToggle}>{showText}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
})

ReactDOM.render(<Box />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your button outside your list first.

```
        <div>
            <ul id="myUl" style={{height: myUlHeight}}>
                <li style={style}>Sometimes show me</li>
                <li style={style}>Sometimes show me</li>
                <li style={style}>Sometimes show me</li>
                <li>Always show me</li>
                <li style={style}>Sometimes show me</li>
            </ul>

            <button onClick={this.handleShowToggle}>{showText}</button>
        </div>
```

Then, you can use this javascript to get the height of the containing ul.:

```
myUlHeight = document.getElementById('myUl').clientHeight
```

Now that you have the height of this, you can pass the height you want to the `ul` (either full height or only 100px. You can also grab the height of the `li` using the same method).

And make the animation using CSS.

If you want to keep this smooth, you shouldn't toggle the display of the item.

You can also look at the library `react-bootstrap` that has a collapsible panel if you don't want to do it yourself: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#panels-collapsible

Comment: Hi, thanks for this answer. I couldn't get it to work because the height I got from the ul's clientheight was always one step behind - it was the large measurement when collapsed and vice-versa. Any suggestion for solving?

Comment: You should get the height at the end of the animation